# Can anyone tell me what to look for in a string to see if its been photoshopped or edited?

Tags: photoshop, image-manipulation

I need some help figuring out whether a photo has been manipulated. I feel that my partner or someone he knows is altering photos which have faces and women and writing in them.  I put a link to the fotoforensics photo where hopefully someone can help me in figuring this out.

He started sending random photos and I helped him a while back look at photos that were altered and so he knows that I'd look at this under ELA and feel he is messing with my head. Any help on how to read a string or if anyone can look at the photo it is much appreciated. The link and the string of the photo is below.

This photo is under ELA, shows no hidden pixels, location is off on phone so very little metadata but has shown ICC profiles in previous photos he has sent. Also there is always warping in places and blurry areas that are isolated. String shows Photoshop software known for layering which is what I suspected. Mind you that these are sent to me knowing that these will be looked under the ELA and are of no purpose to what is going on in our conversations.

https://fotoforensics.com/analysis.php?id=adc55d992cf112a527dae530c83866ff53577038.380597&show=ela

```
JFIF
LExif
8Photoshop 3.0
8BIM
8BIM
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz
&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz
pNkoU
FsTU
yTKF
OLVO
Y.w7\~5<'~
84gMf
r22I
C4oB
UrNx
bqS[O$gq
CsIns
wqG1
Mr7w
EqQAr
psH0k
VRry
GurN
iAyc
W3wt
sIOK
UOLW
VCY7gh
l2sY
Yrn9
pkVp
Wscm
WpPq
UBmlR
9fWe`@`{u
3oAIg
ufEGs
iPu5
8oFy
H7rSC`j
RqUn
128n
W1yk
FXLd
rU?QWmbU<TnU
SF2c
NsJN
nDlA8
1x97k
JuPrNGRz
VrVf
Kgwo
AGS'RSv0/-
TebN
Pups
usm75
pFkr
]_?>`'<{
2FQq
I3UI
P27;F1RK
bMDK
OcNI!9*s
0XTxd
m3BG
5b1Y
9jRg
1Sqr
fiY7p
cwrP
0EqN
i4es
gurd
nfp6
MErN
pFwT
cQIT
W4dv
hxui8
ONEW
Lb9H
s9cI
xpyn
9cla
nyUgg
T5ys
WQmxX
Qioo
WvkOBi52
4jER
ovYG5
qvgQc
eUhih
5RvDCS
YE3Gc
uR0N3\5j
Ygi1
\T4_9"!#q
3w1Vc
GXKl
\3/V#q<`
UsJUm
MONB
4jt4
VHIS
F0GN
6hQD
NERFw
jmvYI
nnN8
8s^uo"jT
FXmQ
4ApI
xItF
sWbFf
VC9v
sSyA
k66f
YXgp
VKGi
lJbA
wJ~lt<^k
GOoJ
MR02A
HGB1
Hw7l
mFRr
6ar1
eY6s
NqOI
Ur9F2
xdrI
3b7d
NET2
k9gK
bFy5
tp2v
0MMo
0xVd
xowD
8Prs
f4R;[YIU#
Xxss
Trxr
o5FhA
OCPJ
HpG9
~_s[vp1Q
lr21Y
4k5tLq
BrEm
sNP1Y
+VRr;W5i
ON=MtvZl
KeXf
UP3V
S3qT
FOsJ
OSPi
VRjn
kjFp1
j7QL
ab0s
YNUI
PYJc
OMYH
=:V;aORq]
bHN85
HynFy
uGRV
QP75HD
RG5H
QJp0jM
j2F8
pFr0Mg
XdsP
D0PB
jm3NQ
jAMf
i7pj
oVBGC
06iA
3KFsH85d
uM9K
3M14Yi8
RMfJ
swJYJ
lWei
u9Nj
Ly3Y
c7qr
SsDE
pOSj
UbNsWs6XSR
3JNG
5bF8
t0F0
dSwf
EQyy
WCbQ
q0:SY~R:
6Llc
krDf
7pEoEf
3Llm
R4sC7
O5k8
sYW2d
2y5Iq
SNKT
4BE-Nnul
rNqR
5RIv
a44t
YovU
ANeV
lXxY
sWbs
UYRH
jIEv
UNO5
5RhH
kVHN
YdbO
sLRI
nOJi
FkTN
HV5n
Yp7n
M8GJ
NROA
mO2ue2
SvO4
2795E
h3qf
RGEkrI
Ck62
udmn
2OJcL
nEFXg
SNbx
uX99
5!p95NW9
1Fc9
2jWM
\g={W[mh
2FMy
k6)Cpjg(
5JIT
VPlU
252r9
pV64r8
NGRk
hOQ3
qNBI
W9QLL
5vi7
U,2zT126
WR08
5mp8
*(hlr*7r=
Q4nv6
Ufec
W36h
OcWbl
TnF1
AISMyF6
A67cc
W9o2
OSQy
Q36s
30nN
lv.E&O=s
Wyuo
ORTY
w5ei
6REW
sHf8
Lwrq
QIlu
pN01T
edvv
PRVg
FVcV
EVPC
TDEH
LTbB
ylWF
Rw^H<zSb
dBYW9
B1QV<W79]
XpG8
VbJq
858a
5VUUS
HNF1
vfUb
iQgqot
MKEI7H0
GOnk6C
}}kZxw/\c
DUPwv
UrGQJ
?!Y4\ebI
M2IAm
dmnv
h388BA=Ny
95BU9
jeM2
Rx5r
jxsT
GpAB
sHeW
sOVl
EVrv
c7nj
U1W1
xlQNv
hBpp9
54Jr2
wr0k
iCMN
PHdA
jA2s
RrFH
WMtG9
eeR9
rRjrrwg
eT7Q
L7gg
RWLi
NqYj
5q0y
WKoq
xYx8
HOCM
2YE5v
rjip
k7PR
SVGw
qMOQ
}+N)~\zW<
CTIu
98lp
#nsY2#n9
V75G
VyXq
prrk1e
V1bF
dp6g
i719
g18l
5CvH
V3EKc
Guk6
uWjm
mMRi
rE5H
3X339a
wNx9
F3XfB
6ny4
nk2s
6XN9
n2GO
5RES
WBbL
aVKe
b5PA
Y6tF
9v4J
Pjle4g_\
WLcc
GQL1a
oqQ4
Ai2y
pHR3
5fF20
VsNI
k7v2
OrjQ
dT1H
ojic
~Q@#<{dTM
@,KQPNT
PbKr1
EHXc
OCIWn
UNI9
i2lH9
62GC
LRhi
Lir6
VdnT
rOOJ
NEGs
Uglg
Us1V
bf~=}F{R
cPXg
6PGNH
p7Sw
VTwd
vOR95Q
u1rl
oJlI
sMhoH
AVPma
h4uP
mDWcg
WcFB
2liC
1qhY
2eFH
rNsU
jBF8
aNESN
mjXN
wpk1
py52N
LprsHXm 
v6lC
BWBrs
JnpFjJ
Frp3
NrOl
WIjN
9bUl
40sd
l66x
5YHl
br0Fx
ZPZjk-57
NY0F8
k6TD
@ ~=j)70
U4Qy
aFrH
QVgUa8w
1mO5
P8b3
wrGo
WJ3k
JIn9
OAS2
CfXyl
4D2W
i3bp
hejl
bpwc
qWPs
pGNx
XK5a
fEN2y
jTKVf
F2y8
7V72H
6SLX
SI0u
WFmF
2)\.N7cozxR
RCl1
HxPq
M4iO
WyUP
Bppy
iY7r
UEjf
MCql
UUBw
Fv6lNX
Rhw*"o=*
JFEWh
hXi7
7Jm2
fbrI
G2clt
TJNpx
UVPO
D0Nx
Kblp
qlPym
Okmoi
oFvdI
QCprq
k6rKc
39nS
UrFH
0LqPO
VpF9
prFq
e7vE
cAFFjBGC
7cL9n
3U00F9
TJ1fB
rMgM
kY1e
DGsF
GJq8
`g?ZC@p95n 
OQVEf
WItwd
B0R3U
e2NA
t8<Ru5L8
X7fT
CdqV
2OBj
.IFF%Ma\
snF1
GjfN
28lg4s
hREB
sY3Q
1VQs
qOBq
2hYG9
SrlJ
eLrq
MjDr8
6RFA
qKvj
uUiA
hbOs
mlv5
Rf3Fq
RFOOJ
iXOs
NpNj
2jGr
D2pI
hnFMI
VReEX
I1Cc
MB0Cd
u681
r1LpO
hqFd
qLix
36Hr1
Frb1
M2Xy
GAS0
n"6E=:t4
cuKp
0wr3
qP6wg
SbGe
R3d8
LUiv
dpFx
VSld
s8>f}kzoC*
R3Y2HS
A9ULt
0jXHQ
pr3C
8rhl
WDfc
6GOO
jjH9
jj0Hw
sG9a
Y3pq
ONFkX
OoOj
qNlF
eQjX
OJll
F0FH
DT6O
EpOs
KSdeL
r2OJ
P2OsJ
9840
rOlS
UShc
9Rpq
qY0mf
BClt
UYKc
#9_SU.$8
54LVR1
QJdP
N02i
5Ixn
b2I8
002j
9nGq
VbF0
WT69
fFDj
3TAj
h0NsN
)C(9^{T3
Qbew
1JKA
S#l`qT$
73gh
NF1X
pOPiH
1VpH
dTX03
c5ar@N3Y
kYlf
c5er
6wR3
S0Gn
nLw3
Ci9o
pNEU
iDAM
QyNG
B4yl
E20YT
jE9l
bi0R
MWn03
YTm8
v7s6
fFldRhM
x5BWev
LNEM
2DjF
ksr0I
UTSHLsd
bqY0BA
NOJk
RD7r
Mfhj
rSars
4QFc
L#7NO<q_
nvQL
H5FVp
kQcS
Lw5m
Qg##4X,Q
7U8T
iwmLT
jRdN
j6fc
Dw3dr
PoRv
s4Ko
5qR1
kJPU
xsLb
wu5N5
JFFO
U~`N}=Mw
bcel
kBdW
SSpb
40dLFvc
Iqj7
59Ls
PHBu
YNT0
HAaJ
DPmn
RcLl
P6Kg
```

[image: ELA shows in my opinio manipulation][3]]

Comment: Photoshopped but this could be just to put it to scale. Looks fine otherwise. What alteration would you expect?

Comment: @xenoid thanks for respose.  The data showed no hidden pixels and there is manipulation in the photo that I can see with the naked eye aloe. Looking at the floor panels to the right, that alone without the tools you can see the warped flooring. Plus the JPEG tables, were you able to check those out? I think layering was used and this would be doe by someone who would expect me to look at photo using ELA mind you. The tools show manipulation pretty heavily from what I can see.

Comment: Think what you want but for me 1) the JPEG format is "flat", and there are no layers, so any "layering" (your own words) happening in PS isn't kept in the JPG, 2) the ELA tools don't show anything (the highlighted parts are those that are overexposed in the picture) and 3)  for what I see, the blurriness in the background comes from the close focus on the fingers and the warped floor can be ascribed to lens distortion.

Comment: @FeliciaBrown What exactly do you mean with 'warped flooring'? I can't see anything odd about the floor boards in that picture.

Comment: @xenoid did you look at the photo i posted only or did you look at photo at the link provided? Okay so you stated Photoshop yet didnt acknowledge how you see evidence of resizing?

Comment: @jarnbjo i think  you should look at the photo again and do you have anything more to provide after using the tools to actually look over the photo? I am looking for someone who has experience in photo manipulation. If you have an knowledge on the tools you used to view the photo subjectively then id love to hear those.

Comment: @xenoid what do you mean the JPEG format is "flat"?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Could you format your post a little better, and maybe summarise what you are actually asking? Do you just want to know if a photo has been edited or not? It might be quite easy to say that an image has gone through some editing, but that's not to say that anything sinister has been done to it.

Comment: There is only on image/plane in it (unlike PSD, XCF or sometimes TIFF that contain several individual layers that are composited to produce a visible image). The layers in the editor (Photoshop, Gimp and others) are squashed into a single image when exporting to JPEG.

Comment: @FeliciaBrown It can't be up to me to look again and explain what I don't see. Yes, I have experience in looking for image manipulations and I don't see any visual hints in the image you have provided and nothing wrong with the floor boards. If *you* think there is something wrong with the floor boards, it is up to you to explain that in more detail.

Comment: @xenoid what about a JFIF?

Comment: JFIF is the encoding (one of the possible two) in JPEG. But it is used to encode one plane (with three channels).

Comment: *you stated Photoshop yet didnt acknowledge how you see evidence of resizing* : what does *"Photoshopped but this could be just to put it to scale"* mean in my first comment? And yes, I recovered the original picture from the ELA site.

Comment: I can't believe I'm the first to vote to close this. It's unanswerable because there's no clear question or even statement of intent; nor evidence to support the musings.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the floor panels and I'm usually pretty good at spotting manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a common error... that photoshop 3.0 tag does not mean the image was opened in photoshop. Photoshop 3 is almost 30yrs old and will not run on any current computer OS; the current version of photoshop is 23.1.1.

> The APP13 block contains data in a format called "Photoshop 3.0". This format is a de-facto standard and used by many applications; it is not exclusive to the graphics program called Photoshop. (This is what happens when companies like Adobe define a general-purpose data structure but name it after their specific application.) This specific data format begins with the text string "Photoshop 3.0". Because it is written as text, it appears in the string extraction listing. However, the purpose is to define a binary structure and not to identify the generating application.

FWIW, "Motorola" being noted in the exif byte order field doesn't mean the image was taken with a Motorola cell phone either.

I cannot interpret the string, probably no-one can.

> "Typically, string extraction floods the analyst with useless information: random lines of characters and **informative text sequences taken out of context**." (emphasis added)

Just looking at that image I cannot see anything that is an obvious edit, and the other tools available on that site do not show edits. I cannot say the file was not edited significantly in any way, but I cannot say that it was either. It is a rather low resolution image with most of the useful information stripped out (i.e. EXIF/IPTC); but some programs will do that by default...

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. This photo was supposed to be taken with an IphoneXR however there have been ICC profiles on other photos which noted the computer owners profile create date which was in 2016 I believe.I dont just look at the photoshop 3.0 as I understand that this in no way means that the picture was manipulated and I know certain photo editing apps that will tag the photo as Photoshop or Adobe.This photo was sent to me as a simple Iphone picture sent to me.The location is turned off as always with his phone but only shows the file modified dates which once can edit.

Comment: Also if I suspect that there is stenography that is placed in the image can there be anything a string can tell you about if that is in the photo? I know  its not going to give away tons of useful information however my question is what can this string give away that would be out of the norm for a photo taken with an Iphone XR or what in this string could lead one to think the characters are more common with Photoshop software and not within an Iphones capabilities?  if theres no metadata what can I look for in a string that would provide any valuable information?

Comment: If there was steganography you might find the readable words of the message w/in the string. But if the message was encrypted/coded then it could be hidden as well.